# About Hyundai Atos 1998 1000cc fuel

Tags: fuel-system, hyundai, octane

What is the right octane number of fuel suitable for car Hyundai Atos 1998 1000cc, 80 or 92?

Comment: Good question because it doesn't look like Hyundai has published this outright on the internet. In most cases for low performance vehicles, the lower RON is all that's needed. There are several places you could look for it though. Check your owners manual. Also, check on the back of the filler door as well as the top of the gas cap for indications. Maybe someone has an exact number for you, so leaving this as a comment.